# UWP Dataset Serialization Schema error in Release Mode, but not in Debug Mode

Tags: uwp, dataset, schema

I am getting the following breaking error when my app is run in release mode, but not in debug mode.

> system.data.dataset does not have a static method GetDataSetShema that takes a parameter of type system.xml.schedma.xmlschemaset as specified by the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute

In my app, I am serializing a large object to a file.  This object has many sub objects, one being a DataSet.  The Schema is indeed saved with the DataSet object when serialized to the overall file, I can see it there, in debug, just not in release mode.

As far as I can tell, there seems to be no way for me to even set this as I don't have any control over the XmlSchemaProviderAttribute for a dataset as I did not create it.

Debugging in release mode is a pain, but issue seems to be in Serialization, not the De-Serialization (but I have not really made it that far).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You could try to contact the .NET Native team and send them a repro about this. Please refer to this: [.NET Native Internal Compiler Errors](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/main/Documentation/ilcRepro.md#known-issues)

Comment: After doing much more reading, I think, maybe, the issue might lie with the need for a [Runtime directives (rd.xml) configuration file to support serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/dotnet-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference). But not really sure what I need to add in there since, I think, the issue is in the Microsoft namespace. I found some info on .NET Native that says [serialization metadata is not normally supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/dotnet-native/net-native-and-compilation).

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, I have tried to contact the ,NET Native team twice via the noted email address on the website and have received no response, any other pointers on whom else to contact? Also, adding Runtime directives did not fix the problem.

Comment: I've talked this with the team. This requires help from the .NET Native team, if the email contact is not available, you might need to open a paid support ticket for this. Please go to https://support.serviceshub.microsoft.com/supportforbusiness/create. Select **Developer Tools -> Windows UWP Development -> Windows 10 Universal App Dev -> Runtime Platform-> .NET Native** in the support page and you could contact the team.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT, thank you very much.  While I have not solved this exact problem, I managed to take a week and re-write my serialization code to not save the DataSet but rather a more general object.  It's a bit of a hack with a translation layer, but it works.   I sort of want to get to the bottom of this anyway, so I will contact MS as you noted.

Answer (score 0):

I finally heard from the Microsoft .NET Native team, and they resolved the issue. As I suspected the resolution was editing the default.rd.xml file, but luckily, they knew how to do it when I had absolutely no idea.

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata"
    <Application>
        <!--
            An Assembly element with Name="*Application*" applies to all assemblies in
            the application package. The asterisks are not wildcards.
        -->
        <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />

        <!-- Add your application specific runtime directives here. -->
          <Type Name="System.Data.DataTable" Dynamic="Required All">
              <Method Name="GetDataTableSchema" >
                  <Parameter Name="schemaSet" Serialize="Required All"/>
              </Method>
          </Type>

          <Type Name="System.Data.DataSet" Dynamic="Required All">
              <Method Name="GetDataSetSchema" >
                  <Parameter Name="schemaSet" Serialize="Required All"/>
              </Method>
          </Type>

    </Application>
</Directives>
```

I would have never figured this out without their help.